# Data visualization of CSV file with dash

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, linegraph

I am new to Python. https://realpython.com/python-dash provides code for visualizing a line graph from a CSV file using Python's dash.

I ran the code below, but receive an error.

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")
data = data.query("type == 'conventional' and region == 'Albany'")
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
data.sort_values("Date", inplace=True)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children="Avocado Analytics",),
        html.P(
            children="Analyze the behavior of avocado prices"
            " and the number of avocados sold in the US"
            " between 2015 and 2018",
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": data["Date"],
                        "y": data["AveragePrice"],
                        "type": "lines",
                    },
                ],
                "layout": {"title": "Average Price of Avocados"},
            },
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": data["Date"],
                        "y": data["Total Volume"],
                        "type": "lines",
                    },
                ],
                "layout": {"title": "Avocados Sold"},
            },
        ),
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/halcyon/Documents/Python/Dashboard - Avocado prices/app.py", line 8, in <module>
    data["Date"] == pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
  File "/Users/halcyon/Documents/Python/Dashboard - Avocado prices/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/Users/halcyon/Documents/Python/Dashboard - Avocado prices/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 529, in wrapper
    res_values = comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "/Users/halcyon/Documents/Python/Dashboard - Avocado prices/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 247, in comparison_op
    res_values = comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, lvalues, rvalues)
  File "/Users/halcyon/Documents/Python/Dashboard - Avocado prices/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 57, in comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY
    result = libops.scalar_compare(x.ravel(), y, op)
  File "pandas/_libs/ops.pyx", line 84, in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I copied and pasted the code from the tutorial as it was shown, but was unable to reproduce it. I tried to Google and understand the material from the traceback log but was unable to comprehend it.

Comment: Hi can you verify that the code you posted is the version that raises the error? Asking since the error message refers to `data["Date"] == pd.to_datetime(data["Date"]` while your code has `data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"]` . This needs to be a `=` (assignment), not a `==` (comparison).

Comment: @patrick It worked! Thank you so much! I had typed that part by hand, then copied and pasted the remainder - I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I didn't see it had been fixed in comments.  A couple of small changes to make it reproducible

  1. dynamically get data from **github** rather than hoping it's on file system
  2. used **JupyterDash** which works out of box with **plotly** 5.x.y

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

# data = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chainhaus/pythoncourse/master/avocado.csv").text))
data = data.query("type == 'conventional' and region == 'Albany'")
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
data.sort_values("Date", inplace=True)

app = JupyterDash(__name__)
# app = dash.Dash(__name__)
```

Comment: Thank you Rob! Much appreciated for your valuable time.